# Onchange Event to Select tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, html-select, onchange

I have 4 model :

class.rb

```
  has_many :studies
  has_many :students
```

study.rb

```
belongs_to :class
has_many :grades
```

studen.rb

```
belongs_to :class, :counter_cache => :student_count
has_many :grades
```

grade.rb

```
belongs_to :student
belongs_to :course
```

on grades/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
        <%= f.label :class_id %><br />
         <%= f.select :class_id, Class.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => "chose class"}, :multiple => false %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :study_id %><br />
         <%= f.select :study_id, Study.all.collect {|x| [x.name+" "+x.class.name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => "chose study"}, :multiple => false %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :student_id %><br />
        <%= f.select :student_id, Student.where(:study_id => :study_id).collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => "Chose Student"}, :multiple => false %>
      </div>
```

how to change value `select_tag`, `study_id` and `student_id` when I selected on `select_tag`, `class_id`, (class `has_many` `:studies` and `has_many` `:students`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok problem solved with javascript